# S-helth in my Samsung Note 5 'none rooted' android 7.0 Nougat, is not working

Tags: root-access, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-note, unrooting, sensors

[image]

S-helth in my Samsung Note 5 'none rooted' android 7.0 Nougat, is not working, I tired so many methods... but no use my phone is not rooted, but I get following message every time I open s-helth, that is "due to a new security policy, samsung health cannot be opened on a rooted device". So can any one help me out

Answer (score 0):

if you have flashed your phone to official firmware using ODIN, be sure to tick BL AP CS CSC on the target download - that will fix knox issues

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. i used Samsung Smart Switch on PC and Connect the Samsung phone to the PC you should find a function on smart switch program called   device initialization. i think when you hard reset a phone some kind of security kick in with Knox  because the problem turn after i hard-reset for a 
 young friend she could not remember the code to her Samsung account and to the email.

[download smart switch](http://www.samsung.com/dk/smart-switch/)

actually after a hard reset the same error show on as yours and did a normal factory reset. and after that it showed another error and then i used Smart Switch